# Using curl command to make a supertest/superagent call

Tags: javascript, curl, mocha.js, supertest, superagent

```
curl -k https://myserver/api/v1/rptoken --cert user.pem --key user.key -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "name=foo&name=bar"
```

I want to use the above curl call to verify the status code as well as catch the entire response from the server. How do I use **superagent/supertest** specifically, in a mocha test to do this ?

Comment: According to [this supertest tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/supertest/info), it's a high-level http library.  Which means the answer to your question is "you would not use curl at all; you would use supertest".

Answer (score -1):

If I understand this correctly, you want to get the status code of the HTTP call.
That would be as easy as adding -I to the curl command (and maybe -L too if you want to follow redirects):

So your command would become:

```
curl -I -k https://myserver/api/v1/rptoken --cert user.pem --key user.key -H "Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "name=foo&name=bar"
```

If your question is actually related to catching the response completely, please clarify.

Comment: I would need to catch entire response for testing purposes